# C# Object Method Parameters representing 2 radio buttons

Tags: c#, oop, methods, parameters

I'm new to OOP. In one of my program's **class**, I'm trying to make a method called **CalcDecorCost**. Here's my problem: I want this method's code to run based on the **Radio button** which the user selects and there are two radio buttons the user can choose from. Is it possible for me to pass any kind of parameters to the method that represent the radio button checked? I've tried using a bool parameter but that didn't work for me. Here's the pseudocode representing what I want the method to do:

```
public void CalcDecorCost(//Need parameters here representing the two radio buttons.)
{
    if(radiobutton1.checked)
        do something;
    else if(radiobutton2.checked)
        do something;
    else
        do something;
}
```

Comment: web form OR wpf OR winform OR mvc razor?

Comment: Well you could pass the radio buttons themselves (or rather, references to them)... it's hard to be more specific without more context.

Comment: Using winforms. I just did some reading and found out that I would need to make instances the radio button as objects to use them in another class which should not be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, get the checked-value from the view and simply pass this as a boolean.

```
public void CalcDecorCost(bool radio1, bool radio2)
{
    if(radio1)
        do something;
    else if(radio2)
        do something;
    else
        do something;
}
```

Comment: This option worked. I used this in the class method. Thanks.